How To Make Progress Bar in PYQT5 Move At The Same Time As Function Being Called?
I have tried everything to make a progress bar I created in PYQT5 move at the same time a function from another file called untitled3.gl_dump is called. However, the progress bar freezes each time the function is called through a click of a button.
Here is my code so far
import sys
import time
import untitled3
from untitled3 import gl_dump
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets,QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication,QMainWindow, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QProgressBar,QVBoxLayout,QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal, QObject, pyqtSlot, QCoreApplication



class Worker(QObject):
    finished = pyqtSignal()
    intReady = pyqtSignal(int)
    @pyqtSlot()
    def proc_counter(self):
      for i in range(1, 101):
            time.sleep(0.5)
            
            self.intReady.emit(i)
           
        self.finished.emit()
            
    
class PopUpProgressB(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.pbar = QProgressBar(self)
        #self.pbar.setRange(0,0)
        self.pbar.setGeometry(30, 40, 500, 75)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.pbar)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 550, 100)
        self.setWindowTitle('Progress Bar')

        self.obj = Worker()
        self.thread = QThread()
        self.obj.intReady.connect(self.on_count_changed)
        
        self.obj.moveToThread(self.thread)
     
        self.obj.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        self.obj.finished.connect(self.hide)  # To hide the progress bar after the progress is completed
        self.thread.started.connect(self.obj.proc_counter)
       

    def start_progress(self):
        # To restart the progress every time
        self.show()
        self.thread.start()

    def on_count_changed(self, value):
        self.pbar.setValue(value)
        
    

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__()
        loadUi("app_interface.ui",self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.gotoScreen2)
        self.screen2=Screen2()
       
        
        
    def gotoScreen2(self):
        screen2=Screen2()
        widget.addWidget(screen2)
        widget.setCurrentWidget(screen2)
        
        
class Screen2(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Screen2,self).__init__()
        loadUi("GL_Dump_Curr.ui",self)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.gotoScreen1)
        self.popup=PopUpProgressB()
        self.main_window_button=self.pushButton
        self.btn=self.pushButton
        self.main_window_button.clicked.connect(self.popup.start_progress)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(untitled3.gl_dump)
               
        
    def gotoScreen1(self):
        mainwindow=MainWindow()
        widget.addWidget(mainwindow)
        widget.setCurrentWidget(mainwindow)
        
       
if __name__ == '__main__':    
    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    QApplication.processEvents()
    widget=QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
    mainwindow=MainWindow()
    widget.addWidget(mainwindow)
    widget.setFixedHeight(300)
    widget.setFixedHeight(400)
    widget.show()

try:
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    
except:
    print("Exiting")

for the untitled3 file the function I am using is below

import win32com.client as win32
import time
from datetime import datetime
month=datetime.now().strftime('%B')
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.Visible = True
excel.DisplayAlerts = False
destination=rf"C:\Users\RaphaelC\Desktop\Important Emails\WIP Special Workings\FY2024\{month}"

def gl_dump():
    data_file = rf"C:\Users\RaphaelC\Desktop\Important Emails\WIP Special Workings\FY2024\{month}\gl transaction download-cc1.xlsx"
    template_file=rf"C:\Users\RaphaelC\Desktop\Important Emails\WIP Special Workings\FY2024\{month}\GL Dump - {month}.xlsx"
    wb_template = excel.Workbooks.Open(template_file)
    wb_data = excel.Workbooks.Open(data_file)
    wb_template.Sheets("GL Data Jan").Range("A2:W5000").Clear()
    wb_data.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:W5000").Copy()
    wb_template.Sheets("GL Data Jan").Paste(wb_template.Sheets("GL Data Jan").Range('A2'))
    #excel.Selection.Copy(Destination=wb_template.Worksheets("GL Data Jan").Range("A2"))
    #wb_template.Worksheets("GL Data Jan").Range("A2:W5000").AutoFilter(20)
    wb_template.RefreshAll()
    time.sleep(5)
    wb_template.Save()
    wb_template.Close(True)
    wb_data.Close(True)
    excel.Application.Quit()
    return None

This is what the interface looks like


As already explained in the other post, creating a thread that just sleeps in a loop is completely pointless. The actual processing part should be moved in the thread worker, but that might work only as long as what gl_dump isn't CPU bound. If most of what it does is dealing with I/O, then it may be fine, otherwise using threading would be useless, and you should consider using multiprocessing instead.

How can I implement this? I've been trying to move the function in the thread worker, but it still freezes.

If it still froze, assuming that you did use it properly, then it means that the operation is CPU bound, so moving it to a thread would be pointless, and you should use multiprocessing instead.

I’m not sure if I did it properly. I copied and pasted the gl_dump code into the worker thread. The function is connected to excel so I don’t know where to place the signals inside the processing function to make the progress bar move. Can you show me what you mean?

Can someone please help?

Research more and ask a specific question with debugging details. See the official sample Mandelbrot. The Python sample is here.

I thought I did ask a question with debugging details.
